# Android: Open fileBrowser to get file path

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to figure out a way for my application to open a file browser where the user can select a video File and have my app store that path into a string to use later. Is there an Intent I can use or function? Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure what you asking for .

Comment: I was asking how I can get my app to open a file browser so the user can select a video. My app would then get the path of the video that the user selected and store it into a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via intent chooser. Try this code i think this solution solve your purpose.

```
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    // Set your required file type  
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "DEMO"),1001);
```

then onActivityResult method.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 1001) {
                Uri currFileURI = data.getData();
                String path=currFileURI.getPath();
            }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code I have used one of my previous projects.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("video/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video "), 33);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 33) {
            Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();
            filemanagerstring = selectedMediaUri.getPath();
            selectedMediaPath = getPath(selectedMediaUri);
            if (!selectedMediaPath.equals("")) {
                filePath = selectedMediaPath;
            } else if (!filemanagerstring.equals("")) {
                filePath = filemanagerstring;
            }
            int lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("/");
            fileName = filePath.substring(lastIndex+1);
            //filepath is your file's path
        }
    }
}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
        // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         intent.setType("file/*");
   startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

and on activity result you get file path.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch(requestCode){
case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
textFile.setText(FilePath);
}
break;

}
}
```