# Android excel file reading by user selection

Tags: android, file-read

Android file reading. I am learning android and a beginner. I wish create an app in which user can can download and excel file into the external storage(I mean accessible internal storage and preferably not SD card). On button click file browser should pop and user can guide to the file. Later reading the file in android. I have seen lot resource folder and asset folder. This is not I want. If anyone have done this please help. Struggling for a quiet long to achieve this. So far using the URI I am able to get the root folder and select the file but not sure how to select the file.

Comment: This works perfect with following suggestion. Thanks a lot..
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23775352/7233554